# Probability that a joyride is overbooked

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A bus operator knows that for every person the probability that a place is reserved, but not taken up, is 5%. The entrepreneur sold for a joyride 320 tickets, but in reality there are only 300 seats.

1) What is the probability that more people appear at the ride  than there are places in the bus?
2) How can I get an approximate result by using the Poisson distribution

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it's **known** then the probability is either $1$ or $0$. You probably mean that the deviation is $5\%$ and the distribution is normal (or Poisson) around $300$.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your comment. Yes, I was unprecise and edited the question now.

Comment: If it is known that for every person the probability that a place is reserved, but not taken up, is 5%, then the expected number of places reserved, but not taken up, is approximately 5% of $7\times 10^9$, or 350,000,000.  The fact that only 320 tickets have been reserved is therefore possible, but so extraordinarily unlikely that, as a good Bayesian, you must assume that the entrepreneur is hiding most of the receipts for purposes of tax fraud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Sum the binomial distribution with $p = 0.05, n = 320$ from $0\leq x\leq19$ to get the exact answer.  This is the probability that 301, 302,... or 320 people show up (0,1,2,...,19 people don't show up).

2) The Poisson distribution with $\lambda = np = 16$ gives an approximate probability.  So $\frac{e^{-16}16^{x}}{x!}$ gives the approximate probability that $x$ people don't show up.  Summing this from 0 to 19 gives an approximate probability.